# How I can show 'My orders' in MY Dashboard?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer-account, magento-2.1.3

I want to show my all orders list in my dashboard .with this wishlist page. I think its in luma by default but I am using a theme so where in xml I have to again activate this ? . [image]

**customer_account_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Dashboard</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

...view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!-- Orders link -->
       <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can use this in a custom module. I believe in can be used in your theme folder as well.

To answer your question. The xml is `customer_account.xml`.

EDIT:

You desire to achieve a custom behavior.

The controller that renders the information you desire is `Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History`

You can take a look at how your current behavior is implemented for Address and Account Information and emulate that for Order History

Also the layout file for the view you want to edit is.

```
customer_account_index.xml
```

Comment: In Order history left side bar I can get all oders , But I want to show under 'MY Dashboard'   So for this where I need to write this ?

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: @Valpea can you have look at my   customer_account_index.xml   ?  where I can add this ?